# Are Questions Actually Being Merged?

Tags: discussion, merging

One of the more powerful moderation tools on the SE network is question merging. It enables the merging of a question and its answers. There are many cases in which this is useful: the questions are duplicates but both have valuable answers, or if they are not *quite* duplicates, but related to such an extent that they should be discussed on the same page, etc.

However, I'm not seeing the question-merge tool being used. Or discussed, ever. It's now about a year since I first started reading SE sites, and it is just today that I've seen anyone discuss the *Merge Question* feature (though I was aware of it previously). However, it's possible that I was just being inattentive.

So, several questions:

- Do statistics exist on how many questions are being merged? (Hopefully this is accessible via SEDE?)
- If the question-merge tool appears underused, what are ways in which it could be improved or in which merging questions could become better-incentivized?

Comment: Here's the list of [merged duplicates](http://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=duplicate%3A1+locked%3A1+), 184 of them. And [this](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/11229/) is an (infrequent, as you noted) example of merging being discussed. I never requested a merge myself, as far as I remember. Outside of double-posts, notation in duplicates rarely matches, so the answers would seem a bit out of place. And double posts tend to be junk anyway.

Comment: @Thursday: You can add another 52 deleted such questions. (What!? You can't use the `deleted:1` parameter!?) But going through user histories, "moderator merges questions" has been done 230 times by the current mod team. I don't have the patience to go through the histories of former mods, but it appears that some merged questions are left out of these searches.

Comment: The difficulty with merging (as I see it) is that if two questions are duplicates, but use different notation, then answers to one of them would not make sense as answers for the other question. (Imagine, for example, seeing an answer which exchanges all $n$ and $k$'s. Especially if the answer does not repeat the claim from the question with new variables, but simply states some short hint. I think that something like that might be confusing.)

Comment: Are Questions Actually Being Titled By Capitalizing Every Word?

Comment: @Thursday When titling, I only leave non-initial prepositions, articles, and conjunctions in the lower case. I believe this to be a reasonable approximation of correctness.

Comment: @Newb [Capitalizing titles](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98066/capitalizing-titles)

Comment: The merge tools are the most scary tools available to moderators. They are irreversible for moderators, for any mistakes they have to ask an SE developer to fix it. So I'm not suprised that they aren't used very often.

Comment: I merge stuff every so often when there are worthwhile answers or comments that I feel should be preserved.  If the merge tool is used infrequently, it's probably because, for the most part, duplicate questions are either caught quickly, or don't contain content that's worth the attention.

Comment: See http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/11814/thread-request-mergers-of-very-similar-questions?rq=1